# Get CustomException: null when throw CustomException in EventListener

Tags: exception, controller-advice

I have CustomException and a class with @RestControllerAdvice.
when i call an API and get Exception RestControllerAdvice catch my Exception (debug goes in the exception handler method) and show the message in console **but** when i throw CustomException inside @Scheduled or @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) , RestControllerAdvice cannot catch my exception and show null in console:

```
com.company.utility.exception.CustomException: null
```